# Unpack Rar File in assets folder when install apk

Tags: android

hi is there any way to put a RAR archive in assets folder and when user try to install apk unpack it and user files inside that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to put a RAR archive in assets folder

You are welcome to put any sort of file in `assets/`.

> when user try to install apk unpack it and user files inside that ?

You are welcome to unpack it when the user first runs the app. You have no means of unpacking it before then, and Android is not going to do anything with your assets on its own.

Note that Android does not have RAR APIs. Either switch to something Android has (e.g., ZIP) or you will need to find some Android-compatible RAR file. Or, since APK files are already compressed, forget about the RAR and puts its unpacked contents directly in `assets/`.